# Client acknowledgement in JMS

Tags: java, jms

Can anyone know to do the client acknowledgement in JMS.

Right now I am using `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT` for the acknowledgement purpose.

I do know how to change my `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT` to `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT`

Here is my code.

```
   public Connection openConnection() throws JMSException {
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = jmsConfiguration
            .connectionFactory();
    Connection conn = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    return conn;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param queueData
 * @param queueName
 * @throws JMSException
 * @throws DataCaptureException
 */
public void sendMessage(String queueData, String queueName)
        throws JMSException, DataCaptureException {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {

        connection = openConnection();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(queueName);
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
        Message message = session.createTextMessage(queueData);
        producer.send(message);
        session.close();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        throw new DataCaptureException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param queueName
 * @return
 * @throws JMSException
 * @throws DataCaptureException
 */
public String receiveMessage(String queueName) throws JMSException,
        DataCaptureException {
    Connection connection = null;
    String queueMessage = null;
    try {

        connection = openConnection();
        connection.start();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(session
                .createQueue(queueName));
        Message message = consumer.receive(1000);
        consumer.close();
        if (null != message) {
            queueMessage = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
        }
        session.close();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        throw new DataCaptureException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
    return queueMessage;
}
```

Can anyone let me know how to change it to `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT` and how to verify it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the creation of the Session to be CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE:

```
Session session = connection.createSession(false,
            Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

then you have to acknowledge the messages yourself in your code:

```
message.acknowledge();
```

You should acknowledge the message once you are happy for it to be deleted. To verify it works is to see if the message still exists on the destination or not.